# Remove comma from ffmpeg output in AWS Lambda layer

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I am using the ffmpeg Lambda layer to get the duration and channels from an audio file. I am then outputting these details to variables to use later in my code?

Can anyone spot/tidy this code so it only outputs the actual value and not one prepended with a comma

[image]

```
const { spawnSync } = require("child_process");
var fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');


exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const source_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Bell-ring.flac';
    const target_path = '/tmp/test.flac';

    async function downloadFile()  {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const file = fs.createWriteStream(target_path);
            const request = https.get(source_url, function(response) {
            response.pipe(file);
            console.log('file_downloaded!');
            resolve();
            });
        });
    }

    await downloadFile();

    const duration = spawnSync(
        "/opt/bin/ffprobe",
        [
            target_path,
            "-show_entries",
            "stream=duration", 
            "-select_streams",
            "a",
            "-of",
            "compact=p=0:nk=1",
            "-v",
            "0"
        ]
        );

        const channel = spawnSync(
        "/opt/bin/ffprobe",
        [
            target_path,
            "-show_entries",
            "stream=channels",
            "-select_streams",
            "a",
            "-of",
            "compact=p=0:nk=1",
            "-v",
            "0"
        ]
        );

    var durations = duration.output.toString('utf8');
    console.log(durations);
    var channels = channel.output.toString('utf8');
    console.log(channels);

    /*const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        //body: JSON.stringify([channel.output.toString('utf8')])
        body: 'Complete'
    };
    return response;*/
};
```

Just not sure where these comma values are coming from and I need these as number values for comparison functions later in the code.

It uses this easy Lambda layer with no external modules required

https://github.com/serverlesspub/ffmpeg-aws-lambda-layer

Comment: what is the output of the `ffprobe` comment ? If you type the command on your laptop, what is the `stdout` ?  You will get the same in Lambda and might require to write some code to parse the output of `ffprobe`

Comment: The command on my Windows 10 laptop with ffmpeg installed returns ```2``` using ```ffprobe test.flac -show_entries stream=channels -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0```

Comment: Lambda runs on Amazon Linux, it would be interesting to test the command on Amazon Linux to understand the root cause.  Anyway, even without knowing the root cause, just removing the leading `,` is easy to do in Javascript.  Check the `substring()` method

Comment: @Gracie `spawnSync` return's `output` is an Array which you're converting to a String. Try using `stdout` instead which is equivalent to `output[1]`.

Comment: ```var channels = channel.output.toString('utf8').replace(/^,/, '');``` has done it. Thanks